# Aliases for sql column

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to understand why this does not work :

```
select my_table.my_column AS 'what I want to write'
from my_table
```

The error:

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

How do I name my column `what I want to write` ?

Thank you

Comment: Double quotes, e.g. "what I want to write".

Comment: ok.. thank you... I erase the question... or not

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes are for string literals, double quotes are for delimited identifiers, e.g. `"what I want to write"`.